# TYPO3 with doctrine - usage of DQL?

Tags: typo3

since doctrine is implemented now, is it possible to use DQL in Repository?
And if, how is the naming of models?

Symfony implemented Models in DQL like Bundle:Model, but DQL supports namespaced Models like Vendor\Plugin\Domain\Model\XY
But i do not see functions like setParameters, setMaxResults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. TYPO3 only implements Doctrine DBAL, but not Doctrine ORM.

However you can use the TYPO3 query builder with the `statement()` method. The mapping will be done as usual in extbase.

Another option is to use the extension `doctrine_orm`. See the manual for information about the integration and limitations:
https://github.com/cyberhouse/typo3-doctrine-orm/blob/master/Documentation/Integrations.rst